# get average hours in php language

Tags: mysql, time, timestamp, average

I have a table with 3 columns:
`id` `start_service` `stop_service`

I have already managed to catch the time difference between `start_service` and `stop_service` using this query:

```
SELECT
  TIMEDIFF (stop_service, start_service)  AS tempo 
FROM
  user_establishment ORDER BY id;
```

Now I need to add all the results of this query and divide by the number of records, so as to obtain the average time of all services.

The main problem is the conversion of the hours.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: The post needs to be in English.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Sorry, i fixed

Comment: Thank you Eduardo. Have a look at an answer given below.

Answer (score 0):

Following query will be used to get average of time difference.
No need to add ORDER BY clause while using AVG() function in mysql query. It saves time to being execute.

```
SELECT AVG(TIMEDIFF(stop_service, start_service)) AS tempo 
FROM user_establishment;
```

Comment: in the "service start" field I have the following time:
03:19:15
in the field "fim_servico" I have the following time:
03:20:18
the result I got with your code was: 54.0000
it would have to be in hours

Comment: It is getting the average result of all the rows at once. I think you are looking to calculate the difference between stop & start in hours record wise? am i correct?

Comment: I need to calculate the average of the difference between start_service and end_service and show the result in hours format too

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you need to get your results in hours. You can omit the division by 3600 if you need to have it in seconds (this is what I would do and then manipulate it in my code afterwards).

```
SELECT
AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(stop_service, start_service)))/3600  AS tempo 
FROM
user_establishment;
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the average time difference in hours upto two decimal points, you can try the below query.

```
select ROUND(AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(tempo)/3600), 2) as avg_time
from (
    select TIMEDIFF(stop_service, start_service) as tempo
    from user_establishment
) as timeline
```

You can modify the average time diff as per your need.